# Error when inputting list of dicts to Bokeh ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh to graph some data that originates from a JSON blob (which is retrieved with Python). I want to pass the original JSON data into ColumnDataSource so that when the user clicks on a point, all of the data in the original JSON blob is displayed (using a CustomJS tooltip). However, when I do the following, I get *'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'*.

Setting up graph:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x = xvals, # list of datetimes
    y = yvals, # list of strings (categorical variable),
    info = info, # list of dicts (each dict has the same 7 keys)
))
```

JS display part:

```
code = """
    selection = require("core/util/selection")
    indices = selection.get_indices(source)
    for (i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        ind = indices[i]
        document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML= source.data['info']
    }
    """
```

All three lists are the same length. I've tried and this works fine with a list of lists, just not a list of dicts. Has anyone been able to get this to work/any suggestions on how to fix this? I am currently converting my list of dicts into 7 separate lists but would strongly prefer not to do that because I need this code to scale for a much larger JSON dataset.

Alternatively, is there another way (besides passing data through ColumnDataSource) to allow the CustomJS code to read the JSON data from Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to call `json.dumps` on each JSON blob, so that you are creating a column of strings, rather than a column of dicts. If you are just displaying the information then it's already a string. If you actually need the structure in a callback, etc. you could call `JSON.parse` on it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Another quick question. If I want to label each individual point with its index (e.g. 0, 1, 2...) is there a way to do so without adding a field in ColumnDataSource that is a list of numbers [0,1,2...]?

Comment: You mean actually display a `LabelSet`? Those generally need to be driven by real column of data in CDS. However, you could probably use a `CustomJSTransform` on an existing column (that just returns the indices as the "transform")